# Does ImageIO.read() take EXIF orientation metadata into account?

Tags: java, exif, javax.imageio

In JPEG images, EXIF metadata is sometimes included and tells in what orientation the image should be shown.

The question is, whether Java's `ImageIO.read()` takes EXIF into account while reading a JPEG image, and automatically applies the transformation.

More concretely, if I use Java's `ImageIO` for converting a JPEG image with EXIF into a PNG image, is the orientation of the PNG image going to be correct? Or is the below code going to produce a PNG image without taking EXIF orientation instructions into account?

```
private byte[] convertToPng(byte[] imageFileAsByteArray) {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageFileAsByteArray);
    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(bis);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(bi, "png", bos);

    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: `ImageIO.read()` will not read your exif. You should use `ImageReader` class to read and copy image metadata

Comment: I don't want to copy any metadata. PNG image does not even have any EXIF entry. I want to have the image transformed according to the EXIF value, then to save it as another format, forgetting of the EXIF entry

Comment: Yes, PNG. Sorry I forgot about this. But anyway you have to extract metadata manually and use it to transform your image. This library is also good: https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor

Comment: @Uata What is the source of your information. All `ImageIO.read()` does is construct an appropriate `ImageReader` for the image type and then call it. Difficult therefore to see how it could avoid processing EXIF metadata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is, unfortunately, no; `ImageIO.read(..)` (by default) does not take the Exif Orientation tag into account. Your PNG will be not be rotated accordingly.

---

However, all `ImageIO.read(..)` does internally, is to look up an appropriate `ImageReader` plug-in for the input, and delegate reading to it. And while the JRE-bundled plug-in does not take Exif into account, it is possible to add support for it, in a third-party `ImageReader`. Unfortunately, I don't know of any that do, but I am considering adding [Exif orientation support to the TwelveMonkeys ImageIO JPEGImageReader](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/issues/288) in the future.

In the mean time, you have to apply the rotation yourself, by reading the metadata and rotating. The value of the orientation tag can be acquired either using the [ImageIO JPEG metadata](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/jpeg_metadata.html) or some third-party library. I think both the mentioned [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) or [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/) can be used for this purpose. JAI ImageIO (using the TIFF metadata) can probably also do this.

If using the ImageIO JPEG metadata, be aware:

> Note that an application wishing to interpret Exif metadata given a metadata tree structure in the `javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0` format must check for an `unknown` marker segment with a tag indicating an `APP1` marker and containing data identifying it as an Exif marker segment.

Answer (score -1):

I have struggled with jpeg exif orientation for awhile, and now that I set out to fix my problems, I find that they are gone. To make sure for myself, I simplified OP.s example so as to read

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {
  java.io.File in  = new java.io.File ("in.jpg");
  java.io.File out = new java.io.File ("out.png");
  BufferedImage image  = ImageIO.read (new FileInputStream(in));
  ImageIO.write (image, "png", out);
}
```

in.jpg is a picture with exif orientation tag 8, tilted to the left. When I run the example, out.png is created as a properly oriented png picture. So it seems that ImageIo has learned something recently.